# Any image processing library for .NET with floating-point operations?

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

I have developed a numeric/scientific application which performs some steps using image processing routines from `Scipy.ndimage` in Python, and now I need to port this functionality to C# in Visual Studio 2010.

The question is that, in Scipy/Numpy, I converted the images to grayscale and then floating-point arrays as soon as they were loaded, and performed every operations (blur, brightness/contrast, gamma correction, multiplying and merging, center-of-mass detection, and a lot others) in floating point space for added precision. I don't need to save resulting images, just extract derived positional data from them (although I can easily convert back and save again as images if needed).

I started to study AForge.NET, but most operations seem to be on grayscale 8bpp or at best 16bpp.

Thus, I have three options:

1. Find some library which have floating-point image formats and methods;
2. Convert the images to `double[,]` (have no idea how to do it from `System.Drawing.Bitmap`), and waste a lot of time trying to get the desired methods from other numeric libraries;
3. Keep doing things with 16bpp grayscale, and live with it, although I have strong reasons to think that it might decrease the quality of my results.

Any help or insight is much welcome, thanks.

Comment: "mage processing" in the title? I think it should be "image processing", right?

Comment: Thanks for who corrected the title, it is in fact image-processing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not take a look at [Emgu](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)? This gives you a managed wrapper to OpenCV, and supports conversion to and from double/float precision.

See [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images) for some simple examples of working with the library.

Comment: Have you worked with Emgu already? How is it in terms in current development and community activity?

Comment: Yep, used it before. Development seems to keep pace pretty well with OpenCV - the current stable OpenCV is 2.4.3 and Emgu is compatible with 2.4.2. It seems like there is a steady stream of activity on the Emgu forums.